# UIButton indexpath is returning wrong path in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to reach button indexpath in a correctly filled UITableView. I have two labels and one button in every cell customized in anouther XIB. When I click the button in any row in any section, it returns mw wrong indexpath. I am wondering what may cause this. Below you can find my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProgramCell";

    ProgramCell *cell = (ProgramCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProgramCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; 
    [cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled: NO]; //


    NSString* strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d/%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row ];

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonClickedArray.count; i++) {

        if([[buttonClickedArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:strTemp])
        {
            [cell.btnHatirlat setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.5 blue:0. alpha:0.7]];
            [cell.btnHatirlat setTitle:@"Eklendi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

    NSString *str = @"";
    str = [arrayPazartesi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    if ([str length] > 1)
    {
        NSString *strSaat = [str substringToIndex:5];
        NSString *strEtkinlikAdi = [str substringFromIndex:6];
        cell.lblEtkinlik.text = strEtkinlikAdi;
        cell.lblSaat.text = strSaat;
        [cell.btnHatirlat addTarget:self action:@selector(hatirlat:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void) hatirlat:(UIButton *)sender
{      
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableProgram];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableProgram indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    int j = indexPath.section; //true section
    int i = indexPath.row; //wrong row
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the output your getting versus whats expected. For example is it always 1 off what your looking for. Or is it completely random

Comment: it returns first two rows' index as 0 in every section. following rows continiues from 1. like 3rd row index -> 1, 4th -> 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this problem before (but can't find the reference), and the fix was to not pick the corner of the button (I think this would only be a problem if the button is right at the top of a cell). Instead of,

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableProgram];
```

Try this to make sure you're not right on an edge,

```
CGPoint boundsCenter = CGRectOffset(sender.bounds, sender.frame.size.width/2, sender.frame.size.height/2).origin;
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:boundsCenter toView:self.tableView];
```

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not working in my case.

Comment: @gbesler, does it give the same results that you get with your code?

Comment: it returns 0 for every indexpath.row value.

Comment: @gbesler, yeah, I did some more testing, and the center property is reported in the superview's coordinates, so when you convert it to the table view's coordinates, it puts the center outside the table view entirely. I've updated my answer to give a center based on the button's bounds, so it will convert correctly. Try this, and see if it works; it does when I test it with a button that's the same height as the cell (but then so did your code, so I'm not sure why yours doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead. I have seen quite a few people complain about this method behaving quite weirdly.

```
CGPoint point = [self.tableView convertPoint:sender.frame.origin fromView:sender.superview]; 
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

**Edit**

The preferred way to do this would be to have the cell create the button (maybe during the init). And define a protocol for this cell, that returns a reference to the cell. Set the cell as the button delegate and when the button is clicked, pass a reference to the cell back to the cell delegate, which can call

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

e.g.

UITableViewCell.h

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)cell:(UITableViewCell *)cell buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button;

@end


@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<MyCellDelegate> delegate;
```

UITableViewCell.m

```
- (void)setDataWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    [self.titleLbl setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [self.amountLbl setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"amount"]];

    btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    .....
}

- (void)buttonPressed
{
    if(self.delegate)
    {
        if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(cell:buttonPressed:)])
        {
            [self.delegate cell:self buttonPressed:btn];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still same. in every section, first two rows', row indexes are 0. 3rd row's row index is 1 and continiues like 2,3,4 in the following rows.

Comment: maybe try assign the buttons tag as the row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and use the above method to get the section? quite hacky I no but just spitballing ideas

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set the elements index inside the `UIButtons` `tag` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?
Everytime you push the `UIButton` **hatirlat** will be called and you can access the index by the sender.

Maybe it will cause a problem because of your two `UITableViews` but I don't know exactly your code.

```
- (void) hatirlat:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    _arrayForPosition[button.tag];
}
```